# Downgrading elasticsearch in docker-compose.yml leads to license error

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
...
 elasticsearch:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
   container_name: elasticsearch-cust-comp
...
```

I've previously run it with another elasticsearch version:

```
...
 elasticsearch:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
   container_name: elasticsearch-cust-comp
...
```

Since changing the version to 5.4.3, I'm getting this error in docker logs for the Elasticsearch container:

```
Unknown license version found, please upgrade all nodes to the latest elasticsearch-license plugin
```

My guess is that version 6.5.4 of Elasticsearch is still running somewhere and that it creates issues when I'm trying to run 5.4.3. But as far as I know, I've shut down all Elasticsearch containers currently running with `docker-compose down`, and `docker ps` shows no processes after this. Still, when I run docker-compose up -d with version 5.4.3, it gives me this error. Running 6.5.4 works fine. What do I need to do to be able to run version 5.4.3?

EDIT:

This is the whole part regarding elasticsearch in the docker-compose.yml. As you can see, xpack is already disabled:

```
 elasticsearch:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
   container_name: elasticsearch-cust-comp
   ports:
     - 9200:9200
     - 9300:9300
   volumes:
     - cust-comp-elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
     - ./cust/externalConfig/elasticsearch/config/hunspell/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/hunspell/
  #   - ./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
#     - ./fwhome/elasticsearch/cust-comp:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/cust-comp
   networks:
     - cust-comp
   environment:
     - cluster.name=i3-elasticsearch
     - xpack.security.enabled=false
     - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
     - xpack.ml.enabled=false
     - xpack.graph.enabled=false
     - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
   restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: because xpack became open only after version 6.3. Please read here: https://www.elastic.co/what-is/open-x-pack

Comment: So what does this mean? That xpack is still running somewhere?

Comment: To use it you need to activate xpack. To activate it you need to provide a paid license.

Comment: Can't I just run it without x-pack?

Comment: Sure, the problem is that it find a license: Unknown license version found in the error stack. Probably the license is located on a mounted volume, I don't know the default path where it is, sorry

Comment: I suggest you to expunge all the xpack params from elasticsearch.yml if you mount it

Comment: I already have set all the xpack-stuff to false in my docker-compose file. See my edit.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to go into the container by using `docker exec -it elasticsearch bash`, but it won't let me because the container is constantly restarting due to the licensing error.

Comment: I'm sorry, sincerly, I don't know what could you do. Maybe you could try if these informations about license are written in a specific index that begins with dot - like .kibana. you should replace es v6.5 and then query GET _cat/indices?v to have a look if there are some xpack indices

Answer (score 0):

In doubt, try:

```
docker system prune
```

This will clean unused containers/images.